# List.JS not doing anything noticeable

Tags: javascript, html, listjs

I am trying to set up list.JS on an existing list on my page. This is a simplified version of what im trying to work with

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="list-container">
    <input class="search" placeholder="Search">
    <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
        Sort by name
    </button>
    <ul class="buisList">
        <li class="even" id="1">
            <div class="buisName"><a class="buisClick" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="name">Century 21</span></a></div>
            <div class="buisDesc"><a class="buisClick" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="desc">Century 21 Real Estate LLC is an American real estate agent franchise company founded in 1971. The System consists of approximately 6,900 independently owned and operated franchised broker offices in 78 countries and territories worldwide with over 101,000 sales professionals.</span></a></div>
        </li>
        <li class="odd" id="2">
            <div class="buisName"><a class="buisClick" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="name">Michaels</span></a></div>
            <div class="buisDesc"><a class="buisClick" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="desc">Michaels Stores, Inc. is an arts and crafts retail chain. It currently operates more than 1262 stores (consisting of 1,145 Michaels stores in the 49 states and Canada and 118 Aaron Brothers stores) as of May 31, 2014.</span></a></div>
        </li>
        <li class="even" id="3">
            <div class="buisName"><a class="buisClick" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="name">GameStop</span></a></div>
            <div class="buisDesc"><a class="buisClick" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="desc">GameStop is an American video game, consumer electronics, and wireless services retailer. The company is headquartered in Grapevine, Texas, United States and operates 6,457 retail stores throughout the United States, Canada, Australia, New Zealand, and Europe.</span></a></div>
        </li>
        <li class="odd" id="4">
            <div class="buisName"><a class="buisClick" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="name">eBay Inc.</span></a></div>
            <div class="buisDesc"><a class="buisClick" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="desc">eBay Inc. is an American multinational corporation and e-commerce company, providing consumer to consumer &amp; business to consumer sales services via Internet.</span></a></div>
        </li>
        <li class="even" id="5">
            <div class="buisName"><a class="buisClick" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="name">Bank of America</span></a></div>
            <div class="buisDesc"><a class="buisClick" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="desc">Bank of America is an American multinational banking and financial services corporation headquartered in Charlotte, North Carolina. It is the second largest bank holding company in the United States by assets.</span></a></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
        valueNames: [ 'name', 'desc' ]
    };

    var newList = new List('list-container', options);
</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.1.1/list.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ive looked over the example code that is provided on their website and I think that I am following the guidelines correctly... but then when I try to interact with either the input field or the "Sort by Name" button, nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

List.js needs to know the class you're using on the list container. This worked for me:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.1.1/list.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
        valueNames: [ 'name', 'desc' ],
        listClass: 'buisList'
    };

    var newList = new List('list-container', options);
</script>
```

Full page here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNQaOg

Comment: Alright awesome - now something is happening. But now, no matter if I click the button or enter a character into the input field, my entire list disappears